# Can I include CDATA section in a VS 2010 HTML snippet?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

When using the HTML snippet "script" in VS 2010 I get:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

I would like the snippet to render the following result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

//]]>
</script>
```

I have looked at the .snippet file for this and found the following "Code" element:

```
    <Code Language="html"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">$selected$$end$</script>]]></Code>
```

and I realized it might be a bit tricky to get this to work, i.e. this doesn't:

```
<Code Language="html"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$selected$$end$
//]]>
</script>]]></Code>
```

Does anyone with a bit more XML knowledge than me know if this is doable?

Comment: I would also like the insert script code snippet to include this CDATA sequence as it seems to be recognized as best practice and standard compliant.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution you were looking for in your snippet just do this.

> <Code Language="html">
>
> <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
> <![CDATA[
> $selected$]]$end$>
> </script>]]>
>
> </Code>

Answer (score 0):

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp): `Nested CDATA sections are not allowed.`

But it is an interesting question.

**Edit:**
The following will work from the xml (snippet) side of things, but I'm not sure how the result will be interpreted by a browser:

```
<Code Language="html"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $selected$$end$
    //]]/>
</script>]]></Code>
```

(note the slash before the closing caret)

This will produce the following output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

//]]/>
</script>
```

This may be something you want to experiment with; as I said, I am not certain how it will be treated in the end.

Comment: I can't get this to work and I dont understand how the code element with no cdata _within_ the script tag could produce that output...

Comment: @Dan: sorry for that; I had copied the wrong section when I posted my original edit. I have edited it again and (hopefully) it will now work :-). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In order to render a CDATA section within a VS snippet Code element, you need to forego the Code element's CDATA section that is normally used and escape the whole content.  If you try to encode just the first portion, the snippet engine recognizes the first un-escaped CDATA section, and doesn't render that.

In your case the snippet Code element should look like this (assuming you have a $script$ parameter defined):

```
<Code Language="html">
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    //&lt;![CDATA[
      $script$
    //]]&gt;
    &lt;/script&gt;
</Code>
```

That will produce the following result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        script goes here
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Finally got around to test this. It doesn't work. I get this when using the snippet ($script$ is replaced with $end$ in the snippet definition):

&lt;script&gt; //&lt;![CDATA[ //]]&gt; &lt;/script&gt;

I.e. &lt;/&gt; are preserved as is and what more is I get no line breaks in the snippet...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This does work - or at least did with the version of VS I was using at the time.  I tested it multiple times before providing it as an answer.  It is possible I misunderstood your requirement.